# React Native call onChange on textinput when state change through network call

Tags: react-native, redux

I have a dropdown list once change a network call is fire and getting some value from server now i would like to dynamicall change the input value but onchange is not firing once i am setting the state after network call.

Input screen with render

```
<SearchableDropdown  style={styles.inputBox}
      onTextChange={this.onChangeText}
      selectedItems={this.state.selectedItems}
      onItemSelect={(item) => {
          const items = this.state.selectedItems;
          this.setState({ serviceid: JSON.stringify(item.id) });
          this.getServiceCategories(JSON.stringify(item.id))
          this.setState({
            CategoryName:this.state.CategoryName
          });
      }}

      containerStyle={{ padding: 5 }}
      textInputStyle={{
        padding: 12,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: '#ccc',
        borderRadius: 15,
        color: '#000',
        width:300
      }}
      itemStyle={{
        padding: 10,
        marginTop: 2,
        backgroundColor: '#ddd',
        borderColor: '#fff',
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderRadius: 15,
        color: '#000',
      }}
      itemTextStyle={{ color: '#000' }}
      itemsContainerStyle={{ maxHeight: 240 }}
      items={this.state.serviceData}
      defaultIndex={0}
      placeholder="Select Service"
      name="serviceid"
      resetValue={false}
      underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
    />

    <Field style={styles.inputBox}
        name="categoryid"
        value={this.state.CategoryName}
        placeholder="Category"
        returnKeyLabel={this.state.CategoryID}
        component={this.renderTextInput}

        />


        <Field style={styles.inputBox}
            name="subcategoryid"
            value={this.state.SubCategoryName}
            returnKeyLabel={this.state.SubCategoryID}
            placeholder="Sub Category"
            component={this.renderTextInput}
            />
```

Renderinput

```
renderTextInput = (field) => {
    const {meta: {touched, error}, label, secureTextEntry, maxLength,value, keyboardType, placeholder, input: {onChange, ...restInput}} = field;

    return (
        <View>
          <InputText
              onChangeText={onChange}
              maxLength={maxLength}
              keyboardType={keyboardType}
              secureTextEntry={secureTextEntry}
              label={label}
              {...restInput} />
        {(touched && error) && <Text style={styles.errorText}>{error}</Text>}
        </View>
    );
```

}
}

input component

```
class InputText extends Component<{}> {

state = {
    value: ""
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
        value: this.props.value
    });
}

onChangeText = (value) => {


    this.setState({
        value
    }, () => {
        this.props.onChangeText(value);
    })
}

render() {
    const {placeholder, secureTextEntry, keyboardType, maxLength, onChangeText, onSubmitEditing,value} = this.props;
    return (
        <View>
            <TextInput
                style={styles.inputBox}
                underlineColorAndroid="rgba(0,0,0,0)"
                placeholder={placeholder}
                placeholderTextColor="rgba(255,255,255,0.8)"
                selectionColor="#999999"
                secureTextEntry={secureTextEntry}
                keyboardType={keyboardType}
                maxLength={maxLength}
                returnKeyType="next"
                value={this.state.value}
                onSubmitEditing={onSubmitEditing}
                onChangeText={this.onChangeText} />
        </View>
    );
}
```

}

Once dropdown change network api call

```
getServiceCategories =(value)=>{

 fetch('http://localhost/api/getServiceCategories?serviceid='+value)

   .then(response => { return response.json();})
   .then(responseJson => {

     this.setState({
       CategoryID:responseJson[0].CategoryID,
       SubCategoryID:responseJson[0].SubCategoryID,
       CategoryName:responseJson[0].CategoryName,
       SubCategoryName:responseJson[0].SubCategoryName,

      });

   })
   .catch(error => {
     console.error(error);
   });

 }
```

thanks

Comment: Post some code so we can see what  and how you are doing it

Comment: I have edit and now code is available don't know after network call how we can render the input so that state change show in input field

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `InputText` component. This component is keeping the value inside its own state and sets the text input value from its state, rather than using the value from the props.

You have two choices: remove the state from the component and use only the value from the props - in this way your component will be controlled by the parent:

```js
class InputText extends Component<{}> {
  render() {
    const {placeholder, secureTextEntry, keyboardType, maxLength, onChangeText, onSubmitEditing,value} = this.props;
    return (
        <View>
            <TextInput
                style={styles.inputBox}
                underlineColorAndroid="rgba(0,0,0,0)"
                placeholder={placeholder}
                placeholderTextColor="rgba(255,255,255,0.8)"
                selectionColor="#999999"
                secureTextEntry={secureTextEntry}
                keyboardType={keyboardType}
                maxLength={maxLength}
                returnKeyType="next"
                value={value} // Use `value` from props
                onSubmitEditing={onSubmitEditing}
                onChangeText={onChangeText} /> // Use `onChangeText` from props
        </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Or keep the state, and pass the value from its props to the `TextInput` and keep the state value as a fallback, in the case when the prop value is not set.

```js
class InputText extends Component<{}> {
  state = {
    value: ""
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
        value: this.props.value
    });
  }

  onChangeText = (value) => {
    this.setState({
        value
    }, () => {
        this.props.onChangeText(value);
    })
  }

  render() {
    const {placeholder, secureTextEntry, keyboardType, maxLength, onChangeText, onSubmitEditing,value} = this.props;
    return (
        <View>
            <TextInput
                style={styles.inputBox}
                underlineColorAndroid="rgba(0,0,0,0)"
                placeholder={placeholder}
                placeholderTextColor="rgba(255,255,255,0.8)"
                selectionColor="#999999"
                secureTextEntry={secureTextEntry}
                keyboardType={keyboardType}
                maxLength={maxLength}
                returnKeyType="next"
                value={value || this.state.value} // Note that now the value is the value from the props and if it will be falsey, then the state value will be used as a fallback.
                onSubmitEditing={onSubmitEditing}
                onChangeText={this.onChangeText} />
        </View>
    );
  }
}
```